# What computer was used in Weird Science?

Tags: identify-this-computer

In the 1985 movie Weird Science, two teenage boys use a computer to create a girlfriend (Kelly Le Brock).  I've seen that movie 20 times or so but I still couldn't make out what computer they use.

I realize the graphics of the computer (along with it's ability to create humans...lol) is not within the actual limits of the computer and that it was probably chosen to be something futuristic looking.

But it appeared to be at least some type of real computer.  Or loosely based on one.

Anyway, what kind of computer was it?

Comment: I think the magic tricks the Memotech could do in the movie were prototypes that Memotech never released....

Comment: @tofro I tried doing the same thing with my VIC-20 but never could get it to work.

Comment: @cbmeeks - Didn't you see what happened in the movie when they tried to replicate it? You fool!

Comment: Interestingly, the lady was named (apparently) after Lisa, another retro. That's at least what Wikipedia claims.

Comment: @T.E.D. that's only because they forgot to hookup the doll.  :-)

Comment: @tofro Lisa was accurate.  That's what her name was in the movie but it was from a girl that Anthony Michael Hall had a crush on.  But then again, the Lisa computer would fit the time frame.  Perhaps his real crush was on Apple?

Comment: Possibly Elon Musk saw the movie and was all like "what's this doll nonsense? Let's get rid of that step"?

Comment: @cbmeeks That's what this site claims: http://mentalfloss.com/article/65434/15-fun-facts-about-weird-science

Comment: Hard to tell without a screenshot.

Comment: In the TV series, by the way, it's explicitly a Macintosh; I forget which model.

Comment: It's disturbing that you've even seen that movie *twice!*

Comment: @paxdiablo you mean me?  I've seen Weird Science at least 20 times.  Maybe more.  It's legendary.  And, I'll watch it again if I catch it on TV.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The Memotech MTX, if you believe [its Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memotech_MTX#Popular_impact). Your assumption about the graphics is correct: it's a machine that uses much the same hardware as an MSX, including exactly the same video processor, but unwittingly and therefore without being compatible.

[image: Memotech MTX]

Comment: BTW: I would remove the MSX reference. Using the same CPU and graphics chip as an indicator for _'uses the same hardware'_ is as claiming all computers being the same for untilize a 7400 somewhere, isn't it? It takes way more than just two chips.

Comment: I'm not sure; the same processor and same video system (including modes, colours, sprites). As a programmer the only difference I'd notice, port assignments aside, is that the SN76489's three tone channels and noise generator differ from the AY's three tone channels, noise generator and hardware envelopes. Especially if you added disk drives, as then I'd be using the Western Digital command set for both. So two (or three) out of three (or four) programmable parts have the same interface.

Comment: Well, with the same logic one could call the MTX TI99/4 compatible. Same graphics, same sound and yeah, TI used a 1771. So again, 3 of four components are the same. Isn't it?  (ignoring, that your choice for a FDC might not be the same the original designers had, thus beeing nit relevant) But lets be serious, a remark about compatibility is only usefull if there is any usage on the User side. Like a Sirius 1 being MS-DOS compatible in a way that all pure DOS Programms do run. I can see this for CP/M programs to some extend, but that's just due the CPU.

Comment: The WD is the chip selected by Memotech for their official expansion, and is that assumed by MSX-DOS. Not one I picked. My answer explicitly says that the two things are **not** compatible. It is a helpful comment since it tells you the capabilities of the machine. The abilities you saw drawn from an MSX are pretty much what one could have achieved with an MTX.

Comment: Then there are many (Japanese) MSX using non 1771 compatible FDC. Fact is, stating that a machinis somewhat like another just becase some chip is the same isn't anywhere helpful, as it doesn't add any information related to the OPs question. Or was a 9918 compatible screen management relevant for the movie?

Comment: @Raffzahn: contrary to your second comment, I **did not claim compatibility**. Despite your third, the claim is that the two are comparable because **all-but-one** of the programmer-facing chips are **identical**, and the other is extraordinarily minor, not that "some chip is the same". I'm happy to respond to comments in response to that claim. I don't see what you're trying to achieve through misrepresentation — "the same logic would call X compatible" (nobody has claimed compatibility) and "some chip is the same" (the claim is: **all** but a minor one are **identical**).

Comment: Furthermore: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memotech_MTX "They were technically similar to MSX computers, but were not compatible."; http://www.old-computers.com/museum/computer.asp?c=168 "It also has characteristics, which are close to the MSX standard, but is not MSX compatible. "; so it's at least me, Wikipedia and old-computers.com making the exact same statement.

Comment: @Raffzahn edited to explain relevance. Also to give you the chance to remove your vote if desired.

Comment: @Raffzahn I disagree. Saying it's using much the same hardware as an MSX computer is a succinct way of describing what sort of computer it was without going into the kind of details you consider irrelevant.

Answer (score 18):

It was a [Memotech MTX 512](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memotech_MTX) with expansion unit.

For future movie-related computer questions it's always a good idea to check
[Starring the Computer](http://www.starringthecomputer.com/) page. In this case, just look [here](http://www.starringthecomputer.com/appearance.html?f=7&c=7).

Comment: Haha, simultaneous answer! You can have my vote.

Comment: Yeah, it's been way too easy, wasn't it?

Comment: I just skipped through the whole movie on youtube, but couldn't see the expansion unit anywhere. They only showed the keyboard. Considering what happened in the movie, I would, however, assume, they were in dire need of that ridiculously expensive unit.

Comment: @tofro did you also notice they used two monitors?  I don't think the TMS9918 could handle that.  :-)

Comment: @cbmeeks There was an 80 column card with a seperate video out, that couldbe added.